# How do I manipulate a line layer to have straight features instead of curves?

Tags: qgis, line, snapping

I am working with a layer (in yellow) that i want to make follow the red line.  I have tried:

1. Snapping - this results in geometry issues where a line intersects itself
2. Smooth - has no effect

Addtionally the red layer does not cover the same extent as the yellow layer and so the snap only moved parts of the yellow layer.

Ultimately the yellow layer needs to follow the points in the same way the red layer does. [image]

I am working out of QGIS and only have access to QGIS (not ArcMap etc)

Comment: QGIS is fine, you 'only' need access to the superior software anyways ,) What's the geometry type and CRS as per the data source? It seems that are *CURVED* geometries.

Comment: Wgs 84 i believe